# Ruby Inheritance of Modules

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

So I have three classes:

```
MyModule::Base
MyModule::Artist
MyModule::Song
```

`MyModule::Artist` inherits from `MyModule::Base` and therefore has access to all of its instance methods and is declared as such:

```
module MyModule
  class Artist < MyModule::Base
```

And this all works as expected.
However, when I attempt to add a third class (`MyModule::Song`) to inherit also from `MyModule::Base` like so:

```
module MyModule
  class Song < MyModule::Base
```

I get a `NameError`. 'Uninitialized constant'. Like `MyModule::Base` doesn't even exist! Am I missing something fundamental about class inheritance in Ruby or is it something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a runnable snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I'm talking in the context of this repo: https://github.com/maxehmookau/echonest-ruby-api the base.rb and song.rb files.

Comment: Yeah, still, reproducing snippet would be nice. Maybe that'll make you realize the problem.

Comment: One note: try using `class Artist < Base` and `class Song < Base`. You don't need scope specifier, you are already in that scope.

Comment: I'm thinking it's something to do with the filesystem perhaps. Even by removing all references for the module and just having it as a series of classes, it still cannot find the Base class.

Comment: How is this related to inheritance?

Comment: Because I'm asking how inheritance works in Ruby.....

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the cause of the problem is very localized, and not related in any obvious way to the question.  Unfortunately, this question is unlikely to be helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at your repo and discovered that while you correctly require your `Base` module via `require_relative` in `Artist`, you use a sledge-hammer `require` to crack nuts in `Song`.

Since there is kinda system-wide `base`, it’s being loaded instead of intended local `Echonest::Base`. Just go with `require_relative` and enjoy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That makes sense, however, I'm still left with `echonest-ruby-api/lib/song.rb:9:in <module:Echonest>': uninitialized constant Echonest::Base (NameError)` When I run the specs :(

Comment: Seems it was to do with permissions on my local machine, though your answer did help so I'll mark it as the correct one.